# P6 primavera thick client(EPPM) cloud connect SSO failing with database version mismatch issue

Tags: primavera, cloud-connect, oam

We are integrating the P6 primavera thick client(EPPM)with Oracle Access Manager (OAM) we have done all the configurations on both OAM and Application side as per the oracle documentation.

The connectivity looks OK, but its giving following error.

```
     The application and database versions do not match. Click Exit to close the application.
     Primavera P6 Professional R16.1
     Expected database version:  PMDB,1610.0001.0001
     Current database version:
```

Though both the expected and current database version is same. Also when I checked [here](http://www.catgovind.com/p6/p6-professional-error-application-database-version-not-match-click-exit-close-application/) I see in the screenshot it does give current database version value. but in our case its not giving any value in the error message.we are using Primavera P6 version 16R1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the version of Database using following SQL query:
`select database_version from prefer`

if this is different from the expected one then applying patches should sort the issue.